# Another way to implement Filebase64

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to upload image using Filebase64, the configuration is working fine but I can't style the button, after searching I found that the button can't be customized and I sound configure my own uploading function, I found a code that implemented it, but I failed to implement it to my own configuration.

My configuration:

```
export default function NewPost() {
    const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState({
        userId: '',
        title: '',
        content: '',
        photo: '',
    });
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/posts/", newPost);
            window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
            console.log('Saved Successfully');
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    }
  return (
    <div  >
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div >
          <div >
            <label >Post Title:</label>
            <input type="text"  
            onChange={e => setNewPost({ ...newPost, title: e.target.value })} />
            </div>
            <div >
                <img src={newPost.photo} alt="" />
                <label for="file">
                    <PublishIcon />
                </label>
                <FileBase64
              type="file"
              multiple={false}
              onDone={({ base64 }) => setNewPost({ ...newPost, photo: base64 })}
              /> 
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
  );
}
```

What I found and I am trying to implement:

```
function App() {

  const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");

  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    setBaseImage(base64);
  };

  const convertBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {uploadImage(e);}}
      />
      <br></br>
      <img src={baseImage} height="200px" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated